# Overriding static file routes in Spark depending on the Accept header

Tags: java, routes, spark-java

I'm using Spark's (http://sparkjava.com/) static file routing, set up via:

```
externalStaticFileLocation('.../public');
```

for serving, amongst others, the **index.html** page placed in the **public** directory. So effectively, when you hit the server's URL, you get your **index.html** back. So far so good...

However, I would like to override this behavior when the request contains a specific Accept header, e.g., **application/rdf+xml** (basically different from the default **text/html**). In that case I would like to return some specific data rather than the **index.html** page.

Is there a simple way of achieving this in Spark? I couldn't find any solution to this in the documentation... Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the change in the behavior you'd like to make, the content you want to serve now is no longer static, but **dynamic**.

You'll need to remove `index.html` from the static content directory and move it to resources directory (typically `src/main/resources/templates`).

Then, you'll need to create a route for the root of your domain name (`/`) and using a [template engine](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#views-and-templates) serve the content.

When using a template engine you usually inject the dynamic data into a static template. Typically you do it using some sort of map.
In the case of `text/html` your map will be empty, and then it's like before -
serving a static page. If it's `application/rdf+xml` you'll fill the map with the relevant data and then serve the resulting dynamic page.

Example:

```
get("/", (request, response) -> {
    if (isTextHtml(request)) {
        // serve the index.html template as is (empty map, not null though)
        // In this case index.html functinos as a static page
    } else {
        // use a map to have all relevant data for the index.html template
        // In this case index.html functinos as a "real" template
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works great @SHG, thanks! Do you have by any chance idea how to enforce a custom, absolute directory path for storing templates..?

Comment: @szymon I don't, sorry. But why not follow the regular conventions of a web project?

Comment: fair point - I'll need to reconsider what and why I really want to achieve that way...